# Vitest expect extend

Tags: typescript, ts-jest, declare, vitest

I'm trying to create an expect.extend in Vitest, I tried following [the docs](https://vitest.dev/guide/extending-matchers)

I created a vitest.d.ts file where I declare this:

```
interface CustomMatchers<R = unknown> {
  toPassGuard(guardFunc: (record: unknown) => boolean): boolean;
  toPassGuardArray<T = unknown>(guardFunc: (record: T) => boolean): boolean;

}

declare module 'vitest' {
  interface Assertion<T = any> extends CustomMatchers<T> {}
  interface AsymmetricMatchersContaining extends CustomMatchers {}
}
```

Still I get a type error here `expect(arrOfSettings).toPassGuardArray(isSettings)`

```
Property 'toPassGuardArray' does not exist on type 'Assertion<string| undefined>[], any>'
```

I found a workaround where I changed Assertion to JestAssertion (which is a sub package)
, and this works but only if the matcher definition is in the same file I use it,

example:

```
expect.extend({
  toPassGuardArray(received, guardFunc) {
    const failedItems = received.filter((receiveItem) => !guardFunc(receiveItem))
    const pass = failedItems.length === 0
    return {
      pass,
      message: () => `${failedItems.length} did${!pass ? ' not' : ''} pass guard ${guardFunc.name}`,
      actual: (`${failedItems.map((item) =>  item)} to pass guard`).substring(0, 300)
    }
  }
})
```

now this  `expect(allEnriched).toPassGuardArray<Asset>(guard)`
only works if expect.extend is in the same file, otherwise I'm getting

```
Error: Invalid Chai property: toPassGuardArray
```

Chai is also a sub package so there is a conflict here I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it, I should have include all custom assertions to a setup file,
and add it in the config

```
export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    setupFiles: ['filesWhereIDeclare.js'],
  },
});
```